# how works applications which blocks web sites?

Tags: networking, system, winpcap

I know only one low-level way of blocking websites - hosts file. However, it is obvious that main stream programs has some other way of achieving this.

I have an idea for new model of this kind of program, but without possibility of blocking sites it is useless :(

Blocking is one problem, another is filtering and replacing content in the webbrowser. Any clues?

**Edit:**

I discovered, that many filtering programs uses open Source library WinPcap. It seems be great for checking which sites user try to open. But of course I need to have some possibility of blocking sites, by for example replacing requested sites for sites with information about blocking. Is this possible to achieve with WinPcap?

Comment: If you're making your own program that downloads websites, can't you simply implement whatever kind of filtering of website URL's (or similar) that you need? I really don't get what you're asking for here. And when you're saying "this kind of program", please tell us what kind of program you're referring to.

Comment: This will be heavily O/S dependant. Some details for recent Windows versions are here http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/device/network/wfp.mspx

Comment: @Lasse: "Internet Filter Software", like those http://internet-filter-review.toptenreviews.com/
Of course I need something which can help me blocks not only one browser (like this: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4351/), but all requests from any browser for specific domains

Answer (score 1):

WinPcap is used for two things: Sniffing packets and sending packets. It can't prevent packets from arriving or being sent.

You can use WinPcap to interfere with some connections to break them or to change them.

Examples:

1. Send RST (reset) packets in TCP to break a TCP connection.
2. Send response packets on HTTP GET packets with your information to get a different result and ignore the actual result.

It won't prevent packets from being sent or arrive, but it can make the client or server ignore other packets and use yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can always write a browser add-on, but an add-on can easily be disabled by the user. I'm not sure if you can block sites with an add-on, but you sure can block what's loaded and displayed on a page (think [Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1865/)).

If you want to make it more bulletproof, then you'll have to make a program that taps into the data stream before it enters the browser. This probably requires a good understanding of the platform you're targeting with your software.

Comment: so my question is, how to access this data stream before entries the browser? :)

Comment: Yes it is. ;) As I wrote in my answer... it requires that a good understanding of the platform you're targeting. You need to know how to hook up a filter without hanging the system. This is outside my domain of expertise. I was just here to give you the clues you asked for... ;) You might be better off hiring or teaming up with a person who has in depth knowledge on network programming than spending tons of time acquiring the required knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the environment in question, you could consider banning various DNS entries if you were in a corporate environment where everyone shares the same DNS servers.  This cover browsers and other utilities,e.g. AIR applications that may also make web requests.  [WebSense](http://www.websense.com/content/home.aspx) is what my employer uses for monitoring internet traffic though this may be overkill for what you are thinking.